# Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint mysql workbench 1

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to forward engineering my schema with MySQL Workbench but this error appears. I'm sure that the foreign key refers to the primary key of the parent table and their are both VARCHAR(45).

This is my schema:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE, ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema PiscineRoma
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema PiscineRoma
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `PiscineRoma` ;
USE `PiscineRoma` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `PiscineRoma`.`Piscina`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Piscina` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Piscina` (
  `Nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `NumeroDiTelefono` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Indirizzo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `NomeResponsabile` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `DataInizioDisponibilitàVascaEsterna` DATE NULL,
  `DataFineDisponibilitàVascaEsterna` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Nome`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `NumeroDiTelefono_UNIQUE` (`NumeroDiTelefono` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Indirizzo_UNIQUE` (`Indirizzo` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `PiscineRoma`.`Persona`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Persona` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Persona` (
  `CF` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `Nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Cognome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Indirizzo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Età` INT NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `Cellulare` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  `IndirizzoEMail` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CF`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Telefono_UNIQUE` (`Telefono` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Cellulare_UNIQUE` (`Cellulare` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `IndirizzoEMail_UNIQUE` (`IndirizzoEMail` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `PiscineRoma`.`IngressoSingolo`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`IngressoSingolo` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`IngressoSingolo` (
  `NomePiscina` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Persona_CF` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `DataIngresso` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NomePiscina`, `Persona_CF`),
  INDEX `fk_Piscina_has_PersonaNonIscritta_Piscina_idx` (`NomePiscina` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_IngressoSingolo_Persona1_idx` (`Persona_CF` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Piscina_has_PersonaNonIscritta_Piscina`
    FOREIGN KEY (`NomePiscina`)
    REFERENCES `PiscineRoma`.`Piscina` (`Nome`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_IngressoSingolo_Persona1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Persona_CF`)
    REFERENCES `PiscineRoma`.`Persona` (`CF`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `PiscineRoma`.`Insegnante`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Insegnante` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Insegnante` (
  `CF` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `Nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Cognome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Telefono` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CF`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `Telefono_UNIQUE` (`Telefono` ASC))
 ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `PiscineRoma`.`Qualifica`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Qualifica` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Qualifica` (
  `Nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Nome`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `PiscineRoma`.`Possiede`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Possiede` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Possiede` (
  `Insegnante` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `Qualifica` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Insegnante`, `Qualifica`),
  INDEX `fk_Insegnante_has_Qualifica_Qualifica1_idx` (`Qualifica` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Insegnante_has_Qualifica_Insegnante1_idx` (`Insegnante` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Insegnante_has_Qualifica_Insegnante1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Insegnante`)
    REFERENCES `PiscineRoma`.`Insegnante` (`CF`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Insegnante_has_Qualifica_Qualifica1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Qualifica`)
    REFERENCES `PiscineRoma`.`Qualifica` (`Nome`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `PiscineRoma`.`Impiego`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Impiego` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Impiego` (
  `Codice` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Inizio` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Fine` DATE NULL,
  `Tipo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'impiego_corrente',
  `NomePiscina` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Insegnante` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Codice`),
  INDEX `fk_Impiego_Piscina1_idx` (`NomePiscina` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Impiego_Insegnante1_idx` (`Insegnante` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Impiego_Piscina1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`NomePiscina`)
    REFERENCES `PiscineRoma`.`Piscina` (`Nome`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Impiego_Insegnante1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Insegnante`)
    REFERENCES `PiscineRoma`.`Insegnante` (`CF`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `PiscineRoma`.`Corso`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Corso` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Corso` (
  `NomeAttivita` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `NomePiscina` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Costo` SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL,
  `NumeroMinimoDiPartecipanti` SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL,
  `NumeroMassimoDiPartecipanti` SMALLINT(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`NomeAttivita`, `NomePiscina`),
  INDEX `fk_Corso_Piscina1_idx` (`NomePiscina` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Corso_Piscina1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`NomePiscina`)
    REFERENCES `PiscineRoma`.`Piscina` (`Nome`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB
PACK_KEYS = DEFAULT
ROW_FORMAT = DEFAULT;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `PiscineRoma`.`Lezione`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Lezione` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Lezione` (
  `Codice` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NomeAttivitaCorso` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `NomePiscina` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Insegnante` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  `Dat` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `Numero` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Codice`),
  INDEX `fk_Lezione_Insegnante1_idx` (`Insegnante` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Lezione_Corso1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`NomeAttivitaCorso` , `NomePiscina`)
    REFERENCES `PiscineRoma`.`Corso` (`NomeAttivita` , `NomePiscina`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_Lezione_Insegnante1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Insegnante`)
    REFERENCES `PiscineRoma`.`Insegnante` (`CF`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `PiscineRoma`.`Iscrizione`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Iscrizione` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PiscineRoma`.`Iscrizione` (
  `Codice` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `DataIscrizione` DATE NOT NULL,
  `CodiceCertificato` INT NULL,
  `DataCertificato` DATE NULL,
  `Medico` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `NomeAttivitaCorso` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `NomePiscina` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `PersonaIscritta` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Codice`),
  INDEX `fk_Iscrizione_Corso1_idx` (`NomeAttivitaCorso` ASC, `NomePiscina` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Iscrizione_PersonaIscritta1_idx` (`PersonaIscritta` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `CodiceCertificato_UNIQUE` (`CodiceCertificato` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Iscrizione_Corso1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`NomeAttivitaCorso` , `NomePiscina`)
    REFERENCES `PiscineRoma`.`Corso` (`NomeAttivita` , `NomePiscina`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Iscrizione_PersonaIscritta1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PersonaIscritta`)
    REFERENCES `PiscineRoma`.`Persona` (`CF`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

USE `PiscineRoma` ;
```

The message log from MySQL Workbench tells that error is in the PiscineRoma.Corso.

I also tryed to run the command SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and under the label the error is:

> 2019-02-14 19:52:03 0x7f9fa9700700 Error in foreign key constraint of table PiscineRoma/Iscrizione:
>   there is no index in referenced table which would contain
>   the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
>   referenced table do not match the ones in table. Constraint:
>   ,
>     CONSTRAINT `fk_Iscrizione_Corso1` FOREIGN KEY (`NomeAttivita`, `NomePiscina`) REFERENCES `Corso` (`NomeAttività`, `NomePiscina`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
>   The index in the foreign key in table is fk_Iscrizione_Corso1_idx
>   Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html for correct foreign key definition.

Thank you all for answers.

Comment: The error message you included has an accent over the last a of `NomeAttività`, is that just a typo?

Comment: The previuos name of the column was with accent, and madly Workbench didn't show any error. Then I renamed 'Iscrizione.NomeAttità' in 'Iscrizione.NomeAttivitaCorso' and 'Corso.NomeAttività' in 'Corso.NomeAttivita' but in the error shown by 'SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS' the columns are called like the old version and I can't understand why.

Comment: CREATE with `IF NOT EXISTS` will not replace the existing table of the same name, no matter how different it's structure; so that could be how the accented a lingered.